# Submitting a book app so that it can download and read in iBooks?

Tags: iphone

Could you please let me know how an app needs to be submitted so that it can be downloaded in iBooks and user can read from the same.

Any step by step procedure or Tutorials will be appreciated!!

Comment: Where not here to code your app, where here to help you with problems that you have when building your app.

Comment: Do you have a specific programming question?

Comment: http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/submitting-iphone-apps-to-the-apple-app-store-a-step-by-step-guide/------- go through this link and if it helps... Be my friend ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iBooks lets people read PDF files or ebooks, which must be in the [EPUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB) format. An EPUB file is ZIP file that contains mainly HTML for the content and some XML files for the table of contents etc. It has nothing to do with native iOS apps.

To publish a book on the iBooks store so that people can buy it, you don't go through Apple's App Store submission process. Apple has its own iBooks submission process or you go to a third party service provider that has a contract with Apple to publish ebooks.

Comment: Actually, you can submit your own books if you meet the requirements (US Tax Id, ISBNs, etc.) and are confident that you'll sell enough books to get paid.